# Reloading contents of scroll view

Tags: ios, swift3, uiscrollview, reloaddata

Is there any way to reload data inside scroll view? I have 5 buttons on scroll view on tap on second I want to reload first button to normal state is it possible?Actually I have table view on which i have 2 rows. Table view cell have a scroll view and on that scroll view I am adding buttons for horizontal scroll I know table reloads but my buttons are on scroll view so I am stuck. Can someone help?

Comment: yes you can do using tag property . set button's tag 1,2,3,4,5 accordingly . and on click of button you can change button state.

Comment: Nooooo! Don't use tags! You can put the buttons in an `IBOutletCollection` (if you are creating it from Interface Builder) or just in an array if not.

Comment: @KKRocks I tried that but when I try to update tag 0 on click of tag1 it is not working .Color never changes

Comment: you don't change tag . you need to set background color of that button.

Comment: @KKRocks http://benford.me/blog/12-dos-and-donts-for-ios-development/ Here you go :D

Comment: @Fogmeister I am adding buttons using a loop. I have a loop that execute 5 times add a view on scroll view first then adding a button on that view and after that I add that view on scroll view.

Comment: @Fogmeister i know that ....in this scenario buttons created dynamically . how to take iboutlet connection of those buttons ?

Comment: @KKRocks IBOutletCollection is just an array so ... `let buttons = [button1, button2, button3, ...]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To update several buttons you could do something like this...

First create an array of the buttons...

```
let buttons = [button1, button2, button3, button4, ...]
```

Now in your target action...

```
func buttonTapped(button: UIButton) {
    // filter buttons to get the ones not tapped
    buttons.filter { $0 != button }
    // set them all to be deselected
           .forEach { $0.isSelected = false }
}
```

Or something like this.

It really depends on how you are creating them etc but this would be a very simple approach to it without knowing more about your specific case.

Answer (score 1):

Just call

```
tableView.reloadRows(at: [IndexPath], with: UITableViewRowAnimation)
```

and in TableViewDataSource method:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
```

setup your ScrollView with buttons again

Comment: as I said I have scroll view on  table view cell and buttons on scroll view . How can i reload using this method? I know it works perfect for tables.

Comment: You said "Table view cell have a scroll view and on that scroll view I am adding buttons". So this buttons are inside TableViewCell or not? If they are not just get the IBOutlet for them and you can do whatever you want with it